# compare string line by line

Tags: vb.net, compare, streamreader, streamwriter

Anybody here can help me with this

Input file

```
  Type Reference      
   WIN  00001  
   WIN  00001   
   WIN  00001  
   MAC  00001  
   MAC  00001
```

Basically I need to compare if the first 3 character that are not equal

preferred output will be

Type Reference

```
   WIN  00001  
   WIN  00001   
   WIN  00001
```

Code below

```
Dim fh As StreamReader
Dim os as string
fh = new StreamReader("haggis.txt")
Dim s As String = fh.ReadLine()
While not s Is Nothing
   os = s.Substring(0,3) 
   if os <> os then
      Console.WriteLine("Write here")
   else

   end if    

   s = fh.ReadLine
End While
fh.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: `os <> os` will always be false - you need another variable to remember the os of the previous row, or compare `os` to `s.Substring(0,3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a previousOS variable, and compare it with that.

e.g.

```
Dim fh As StreamReader
Dim previousOS as string REM to see what previous os was
Dim os as string
fh = new StreamReader("haggis.txt")
Dim s As String = fh.ReadLine()
While not s Is Nothing
  previousOS = os 
  REM save the old os in this variable before assigning it to a new variable
  os = s.Substring(0,3) 
REM check if the new os is equal to the previousOS string (null check if it the first time read
if previousOS <> Nothing AndAlso previousOS <> os then
   Console.WriteLine("Write here")
else

end if    

s = fh.ReadLine
End While
fh.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works but still reading line 5 which is MAC 00001. I want to stop reading if the two value are not equal. I used Force Exit. it is safe?

Comment: You should use previousOS, if you don't want the new different value. How are you force exiting? (well you should at least close your stream first, then run Environment.Exit)

Answer (score 0):

@Yet Another Geek, you're close, If you don't want to just close the program you could close the stream and then put an Exit Sub call in the else statement.  This would take you back to whatever called the sub and continue processing.